# How could I rewrite this for loop in list comprehensions

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, list-comprehension

I got a "for loop" like this:

```
for dirctory in dirs:
    for item in os.walk(dirctory):
        for i in item[2]:
            i = os.path.join(item[0], i)
            if is_image(i):
                images.append(i)
```

And I tried to rewrite it into list comprehensions, I tried this:

```
images.extend(filter(is_image, [item[0]+i for i in item[2] for item in os.walk(dirctory)]))
```

It says UnboundLocalError: local variable 'item' referenced before assignment

So I tried this:

```
images.extend(filter(is_image, [(item[0]+i for i in item[2]) for item in os.walk(dirctory)]))
```

It says TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, generator found

I use Python 2.7.4 in OS X.

Comment: Not an expert in python, but the corresponding list comprehension for the code above is probably a bit long and hard-to-read. It also has side effects which I think you'd usually avoid doing in a list comprehension. *edit* Ah nvm, I see you only intend to use list comprehension for part of the code. Whoops. I would say it's still a bit long though

Comment: I'd personally leave it as nested loops for clarity and readability.

Comment: Ask your self why do you want it as list comprehension? for my point of view if it's to hard to read and to understand list comprehension is not what you want. just think that someone else need to understand this list comprehension....

Comment: one deficiency in your code - getting all components as single item reduces readability. Explicit naming of variables is better in similar cases than obscure indices.

Comment: ``all_directories = chain(*map(os.walk, dirs))``
``full_filenames = lambda root, dirs, files: map(lambda file: os.path.join(root, file), files)`` ``image_files = filter(is_image, starmap(full_filenames, all_directories)``

Comment: @KobiK Firstly, I used list comprehension to create a function to get all the images in some directory, but there's some logical error, then I try to fixed based on the former easy-to-understand list comprehension, but don't know how. At last, I use for-loop instead, and post this just as a technical problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[os.path.join(item[0], i) for directory in dirs for item in os.walk(dirctory) for i in item[2] if is_image(os.path.join(item[0], i))]
```

Comment: Using filter(), I can only use os.path.join once, would this be better? like this:         images.extend(filter(is_image, [os.path.join(p, f) for p, _, files in os.walk(dirctory) for f in files]))

Answer (score 1):

```
def check_image(directory, file_name):
    file_name = os.path.join(directory, file_name)
    return is_image(file_name), file_name

[full_path
     for current_dir in dirs
     for parent_dir, _, files in os.walk(current_dir)
     for current_file in files
     for isimage, full_path in [check_image(parent_dir, current_file)]
         if isimage]
```

The `check_image` function is there to avoid applying `os.path.join` twice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it may be done (it is not exactly what I tested)

```
[os.path.join(path+fname)  for path, _, files in os.walk('some_folder') 
 for fname in files if os.image(os.path.join([path,fname]))]
```

but - if you pay attention - you have to join path twice in this solution, so straightforward nested loop may be more efficient

**EDIT:**

In my example I was looking for Python files by extension, so in that case list comprehension did not suffer from double joining of path/file name

Comment: Any other good idea to get all the files' path without using os.walk?  BTW, is os.image a typo?